# Return django object in json and inject it to another json

Tags: python, json, django

I search everywhere but i can't find answer. How i can for example return all news posts in django in format like:
`{'status': 1, data: here_django_posts}`. I can use serialize but how then add it to another json object? When I put serialized data to `json.dumps` then my `data` is converted to json again. i wish do something like in php:

```
$a = array();
$a['status'] = 1;
$a['data'] = here_my_django_posts
json_encode($a)
```

Comment: `a['data'] = json.loads(here_my_django_posts)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'm tired today. Here is working code:

```
products = serializers.serialize("json", products_model)
return jsonResponse(1, products)
def jsonResponse(status, data=None):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 1, 'data': json.loads(data)}), content_type="application/json")
```